# Need help in importing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, import

I am getting an error while I am trying to import tensorflow.

THIS IS MY ERROR MESSAGE

> import tensorflow as tf
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
>     Referenced from: /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
>     Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>    in /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in 
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 98, in 
>       from tensorflow_core import *
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/**init**.py", line 40, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 50, in **getattr**
>       module = self._load()
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 44, in _load
>       module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
>     Referenced from: /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
>     Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>    in /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to importing TensorFlow? Is it inside a conda environment? how did you installed it? Which version of python/conda are you using? Which version of TensorFlow? Add some info to your question, that should help in solving your problem.